# How to make stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How I can make a stored procedure for following code.

```
use Test    
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(120)    
SET @Str = 'company name'    
DECLARE @End INT    
DECLARE @Split INT    
SET @Split = 40

declare @SomeTable table
(
  Content varchar(120)
)

WHILE (LEN(@Str) > 0)    
BEGIN
    IF (LEN(@Str) > @Split)
    BEGIN
        SET @End = LEN(LEFT(@Str, @Split)) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(LEFT(@Str, @Split)))

        INSERT INTO @SomeTable VALUES (RTRIM(LTRIM(LEFT(LEFT(@Str, @Split), @End))))

        SET @Str = SUBSTRING(@Str, @End + 1, LEN(@Str))
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @SomeTable VALUES (RTRIM(LTRIM(@Str)))
        SET @Str = ''
    END
END

SELECT *
FROM @SomeTable
```

Comment: Have you *tried* adding your code to a stored procedure?

Comment: Some very basic searching would give you plenty of tutorials and examples on this. Sorry, but downvote for lack of effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ThisIsNotHard
  @Str VARCHAR(120),
  @Split INT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @SomeTable table
  (
    Content VARCHAR(120)
  );

  WHILE (LEN(@Str) > 0)    
  BEGIN
      IF (LEN(@Str) > @Split)
      BEGIN
        SET @End = LEN(LEFT(@Str,@Split))-CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(LEFT(@Str, @Split)));

        INSERT @SomeTable(Content) SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(LEFT(LEFT(@Str,@Split),@End)));

        SET @Str = SUBSTRING(@Str,@End+1,LEN(@Str));
      END
      ELSE
      BEGIN
        INSERT @SomeTable(Content) SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(@Str));
        SET @Str = '';
      END
  END

  SELECT Content FROM @SomeTable;
END
GO
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
EXEC dbo.ThisIsNotHard @Str = 'Company name', @Split = 40;
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I tried myself on Google but didn't succeed. I put my question here and a person gave me negative vote. Will the users get any credits for giving negative points to other users ??

Comment: @user2906622 No, there are no credits for down-voting questions. It is done to encourage people to ask better questions (or to not ask questions that simple research can solve quicker). For example, [a Google search for "basic stored procedure syntax"](https://www.google.com/search?q=basic+stored+procedure+syntax) yielded plenty of hits...

Answer (score 2):

The simplest case to turn that into a stored procedure would be:

```
use Test    

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[IGotSomeoneonStackOverflowToWriteThisforMe]
AS

DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(120)    
SET @Str = 'company name'    
DECLARE @End INT    
DECLARE @Split INT    
SET @Split = 40

declare @SomeTable table
(
  Content varchar(120)
)

WHILE (LEN(@Str) > 0)    
BEGIN
    IF (LEN(@Str) > @Split)
    BEGIN
        SET @End = LEN(LEFT(@Str, @Split)) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(LEFT(@Str, @Split)))

        INSERT INTO @SomeTable VALUES (RTRIM(LTRIM(LEFT(LEFT(@Str, @Split), @End))))

        SET @Str = SUBSTRING(@Str, @End + 1, LEN(@Str))
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @SomeTable VALUES (RTRIM(LTRIM(@Str)))
        SET @Str = ''
    END
END

SELECT *
FROM @SomeTable

GO

EXEC [dbo].[IGotSomeoneonStackOverflowToWriteThisforMe]
```